Could anyone identify this HVAC gasket?
I need to connect (reversibly) two HVAC duct fittings. Typically, I purchase couplings in which the male part has an endless round gasket, as shown in the picture. Each gasket has 2 flexible thin "skirts" which neatly seal the connection, and yet allow for ducts to be disconnected when needed (w/o using aluminum tape, silicone sealant etc). This time I made my own ducts out of a non-standard sheet metal. What's the name for this special sealing gasket? I tried squeezing O-rings and C-profile gaskets between two ducts, it never worked. If there are other options, would be great to know!
Many thanks in advance!
P.S. the only product I found by googling which looked like the right thing was an alibaba item, with an MOQ of 1000.


RDMan, OK. The wiki has this definition of an O-ring: "An O-ring, also known as a packing or a toric joint, is a mechanical gasket in the shape of a torus; it is a loop of elastomer with a round cross-section, designed to be seated in a groove and compressed during assembly between two or more parts, forming a seal at the interface." My application does not seem to fit this definition.

The feature you call "skirt" I've heard called a "lip". The part as a whole I've only heard called a "seal," never anything more specific than that. Seals with a lip are commonly found in hydraulic applications like rams and pumps which are machined to have a perfect round shape and smooth bore. It seems pretty "over the top" to use such a seal in a simple HVAC duct application. Round duct work is built of flat, thin sheet metal rolled into a circle - but the seam is not flattened and the profile is not perfectly round so such a seal would be hard to work with and ineffective.

I've got to agree as it has a U, E, or F profile that's not an O ring, I's also not a gasket, gaskets are flat.   It's some sort of wiper seal.

Thank you, Greg. Will keep searching for a "seal with a lip". I also saw smth called a "V-ring" (as opposed to an "O-ring) used to contain oil in a bearing on a rotating shaft. But it was a rather thick piece of rubber and not very "squishable". I also agree that this kind of seal is not perfect, due to a "bump" where the flat metal is rolled into a circle and spot-welded. My system is pressurized, thus, a slight air leak at that "bump" does not seem affect the application.

Greg's term "lip" and Jasen's "F-profile" were key -- many thanks! Here is a part offerred by a Polish manufacturer that appears to be the right thing. Dimensions are in mm.
"Double lip gasket for ventilation fitting"
https://gumotest.pl/sklep/en/gaskets-of-ventilation-systems/805-double-lip-gasket-of-ventilation-fitting-k-1-fi125.html

